# Conectar con AWS desde C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, aws

Tengo una Aplicacion escrita en `C# winform` y la base de datos (`SQLSERVER EXPRESS`) esta en AWS (Amazon Web Services).
Estoy usando un String de conexion como este:

```
namespace Datos  
{
    public class Configuracion
    {
        static private string cadenaConexion = 
            "Server=awsdb.ch13dwiieryvs.us-east-21.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Database=dbforTest;User Id=UserName;Password=UserPass*;";  

        public static string CadenaConexion
        {
            get { return Configuracion.cadenaConexion; }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Que opciones tengo para proteger mis datos de conexión y que viajen de forma segura cada vez que se realice una petición al servidor en la web?. 
Lo que quiero es lograr una encriptación de mis credenciales o algo parecido. Existe forma de lograrlo?

Comment: Parece más bien una pregunta de redes o bases de datos que de programación en sí. Podrías conectarte a través de SSL para que la comunicación entre cliente y servidor esté encriptada. Échate un ojo a [este artículo](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx) de la documentación.

Comment: frikinside lo que busco es poder ocultar mi String de Conexion. Ahora mismo si se utiliza un capturador de paquetes tengo la debilidad de que queda expuerto mi nombre de instancia, nombre de usuario y clave en aws. Creo que ahora si me podras orientar de mejor manera.

Comment: Hola, puedes usar la clase `System.Security.SecureString` para almacenar tu cadena de conexión.

Comment: @xpajo precisamente por eso que me comentas (por ejemplo un _sniffer_), te hablo en el primer comentario de realizar la conexión a través de SSL (Secure Sockets Layer). De este modo la comunicación entre cliente y servidor (tu aplicación y el servidor de base de datos) queda encriptada. Un capturador de paquetes capturaría paquetes encriptados y no información en texto plano. Revisa el enlace que te indico en el primer comentario.